# Not able to find javax.faces.ViewState from the http response

Tags: regex, jsf, xpath, jmeter, correlation

I developing scripts for Jmeter. In the login page I have a parameter for javax.faces.ViewState...

I recorded the scripts and while playing back..

none of the http response I could not find this variable (javax.faces.ViewState) anywhere in the DOM.

Please advice

Comment: Is state saving set to `CLIENT` in your application?

Comment: Can you show the code where "In the login page I have a parameter for javax.faces.ViewState"?